# Spring REST not creating _method hidden element

Tags: spring-mvc

I used to have it working fine, somehow after some development I realized the HTML element _method is not created automatically on the page thus REST does not work.

Below is my web.xml which contains the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
             /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/*-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/errors/403.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/errors/405.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/500.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

what I have tried

- Maven Update Project
- Maven Clean > Maven Install
- Clear the working directory

**UPDATED**

Portion of my jsp

```
<html:form modelAttribute="user" id="user-form" formUrl="/user">
```

form.tag which translate it to Spring form

```
<form:form modelAttribute="${modelAttribute}" id="${id}"
    action="${processedFormUrl}" class="form-horizontal" 
            target="${target}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
       <jsp:doBody />
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

Comment: can you please share the page from which you are making the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HiddenHttpMethodFilter is required only if your form-method is other than post i.e. its PUT/DELETE, in that case spring automatically adds _method hidden field with correct form-method.

In case you want to make a put request change `method="put"` and spring-form will take care of rest

**EDITTED**
I looked at spring FormTag source code, and I found the below

```
 if (!isMethodBrowserSupported(getMethod())) {
                assertHttpMethod(getMethod());
                String inputName = getMethodParameter();
                String inputType = "hidden";
                tagWriter.startTag(INPUT_TAG);
                writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, inputType);
                writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, NAME_ATTRIBUTE, inputName);
                writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, VALUE_ATTRIBUTE, processFieldValue(inputName, getMethod(), inputType));
                tagWriter.endTag();
}


    protected boolean isMethodBrowserSupported(String method) {
            return ("get".equalsIgnoreCase(method) || "post".equalsIgnoreCase(method));
        }
```

So _method hidden field will be added only if your form method is not get/post.

For your case, when delete button is clicked, you can add a input hidden tag for _method field using jquery before subitting,

```
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "_method").val("DELETE");
            $('form#yoorFormID').append(input).submit();
```

Comment: I have another project with the same configuration. Even though the form method is `post`, I am able to see the generated hidden field for `_method`

Comment: in case your form method is post, it wont make a difference if _method is present or not. In your rest controller what method type you are using that is not working ?

Comment: It makes a difference for my case. When user presses delete button, I use jQuery to update the `_method` value to `delete`, hence the request will be transformed to delete instead of post.

Comment: Nice coding inspection.I'll have to do the same next time and check why my other project works out of the box. Thanks again.